# Total area of polygons over latitudes

Tags: qgis, r

I'd like to calculate the total area of several polygons along a north-south axis. A bit like this http://www.closr.it/canvas/1307/#/spot

[image: total area ~ latitude]

There is a similar question with R :
[Spatial graphing, distribution of polygon area over latitudes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24537/spatial-graphing-distribution-of-polygon-area-over-latitudes) . But I was wondering if there was not a simpler solution with QGIS, and if possible in a continuous way, not a discrete one.

Comment: Actually this answer is great : http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24541/51989
But it is designed for the intersection with 1 polygon and I'd like to get the sum of all the polygons inside each row. I'm trying to edit the code but have some problems...

Comment: A minor modification (simplification, actually) of the `R` code at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33449 will give you your continuous solution. The code conducts a vertical (north-south) line sweep, finding its intersection with a polygon (or, just as easily, a set of polygons). You simply want to track the total length of the intersection. When you use a cylindrical equal-area projection, these lengths are exactly what you want to be plotting in your graph (which does not actually show total area: it is the area *density* per unit distance north-south).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but this code is a bit tricky for me since I don't have that much experience with R. I don't know how to edit it to get what I want. Instead, I used a grid and summed intersecting area by row. Then I plotted the sum ~ Y_MAX of the row. It's discrete but still accurate.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @whuber:

> A minor modification (simplification, actually) of the R code at
>   gis.stackexchange.com/a/33449 will give you your continuous solution.
>   The code conducts a vertical (north-south) line sweep, finding its
>   intersection with a polygon (or, just as easily, a set of polygons).
>   You simply want to track the total length of the intersection. When
>   you use a cylindrical equal-area projection, these lengths are exactly
>   what you want to be plotting in your graph (which does not actually
>   show total area: it is the area density per unit distance
>   north-south).